# SCPI - Is there something better?

Tags: embedded

SCPI = Standard Commands for Programmable Instruments

I am working on a instrument and thinking about implementing SCPI as the interface between the instrument and the external world.

I realize that SCPI is quite popular as a standard interface for instrument control but looks like it is a standard that is circa 1999.  So I have the following questions

- Is SCPI an outdated spec?

  Is there something better?

  Are there an commercial token parsers available in C/C++ that I can
  buy instead of writing from scratch.

Would like to hear from someone who may have done something like this.

Pedro

Answer (score 8):

SCPI is very much an alive standard in the test and measurement world. So I wouldn't call it outdated.

Something better? I guess this depends on your definition of "better". It works well if your data types are limited to strings and numbers. As all you are doing is pushing strings around, you can use some pretty simple communication mechanisms. It lends itself well to poking around interactively. And there are ways to express concurrency and synchronization.

Where SCPI doesn't work well is if you need more complex data types, or have large volumes of binary data to transfer. If you are rolling your own, I'd look at JSON as a communications format.

Answer (score 1):

SCPI is very standard interface for controlling hardware and almost every major manufacturer provides an interface for programming in SCPI. You can use `PyVISA` which is a python based interface and works with `LabVIEW VISA` software. So with `python` you can implement your logic simply.